# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library

Tags: php, symfony, php-7

I have run Symfony on my ubuntu 16.04 it returned start up error.
And I ran the php --ini command in cmd

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_curl.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_curl.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_mbstring.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_mbstring.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_pdo_pgsql.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_pdo_pgsql.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_pgsql.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_pgsql.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php/7.0/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
```

Above warning occurs when running the php --ini command.
How to resolve the warnings Also I have purged and installed the php7.
I removed the comment in php.ini extension for some dll

Comment: `php -r "echo php_ini_loaded_file();"`

Will show in CLI current ini loaded file, search there for Your extension, path to it is incorrect.`

Comment: @AlivetoDie the above command also return the same warning error with display the path '/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini' I have edited the path in the output

Comment: what is the question here? you have a warning about missing files. So what do you want to do about it?

Comment: When I ran symfony `Elasticsearch-PHP requires cURL, or a custom HTTP handler.` this error occurs so I uncomment the php-curl.dll in php.ini file after I ran symfony the above warning error occurs. how to proceed further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library ... is Error Can't run commands and you have not installed this extensions.

First stop Symfony:

```
php bin/console server:stop
```

Then

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-curl php7.0-mbstring php7.0-pgsql php7.0-intl
```

After installing run Symfony:

```
php bin/console server:start
```

Comment: I have run the above commands but the warning still occurs but the `Elasticsearch-PHP requires cURL, or a custom HTTP handler.` this error was resolved. Do you know why?

Comment: Restart the apache